# GOlang base64 :“illegal base64 data at input byte 8” at String convert

Tags: string, base64, go, byte

desde hace algunos dias note que al guardar ciertos valores en mi base de datos en algunos casos perdía una letra al final o se agregaban caracteres de "=". Después de hacer muchas pruebas en el debugger logre dar con el momento en el que esto ocurre.

lamentablemente no puedo mostrar el código original aquí pero aislé el proceso que genera el error para poder mostrarlo con un ejemplo.

esto ocurre al convertir mis datos de tipo string a base64. cuando la cantidad de caracteres es 4 o múltiplo de 4 no hay ningún problema. pero de no ser el caso señala el ultimo caracter como un "illegal base64 data at input byte 8" he intentado cambiar el segmento de codigo unas cuantas veces con lo que he encontrado en la documentación usando :

```
base64.StdEncoding.WithPadding('\xff').DecodeString("123456789")
```

```
base64.StdEncoding.Strict().DecodeString("123456789")
```

pero el problema persiste. he estado contemplando hacer ciclos para verificar que el string tenca un largo múltiplo de 4 pero esto afectaría gravemente la funcionalidad del sistema.

alguien sabe una solución para evitar ese error en el ultimo carácter de la cadena?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/base64"
)
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    data2, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("123456789")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR :" ,err)
    }
    data1 := base64.StdEncoding.Strict().EncodeToString(data2)
    fmt.Println(data1)
    fmt.Println(data2)
}
```

este es el output

Hello, playground

ERROR : illegal base64 data at input byte 8

12345678

[215 109 248 231 174 252]

Answer (score 0):

Lo tienes al reves, Decode significa dame un base64 y te devuelvo el los datos que tenias ([]byte).
Encode significa dame cualquier tipo de []byte (una imagen por ejemplo) y te doy un string en base64.

**Código:**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    data3 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("123456789"))
    data4, err := base64.StdEncoding.Strict().DecodeString(data3)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR :", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data3)
    fmt.Println(string(data4))
}
```

**Ejecución:**

```
$ go run main.go
Hello, playground
MTIzNDU2Nzg5
123456789
```